# Inconsistency between shapefile imported QGIS and R

Tags: qgis, shapefile, r, geometry, import

I have a shapefile downloaded from [here](https://www.marineregions.org/downloads.php#longhurst) (longhurst marine provinces). When one views the shapefile in QGIS via a simple drag and drop all polygons are well displayed. Shown here:

[image: From QGIS]

However, importing the polygon into R and plotting somehow has problems with the geometry (notice the solid fill in the arctic region for Canada and Greenland)

[image: From R]

I have tried verifying geometries in QGIS then exporting the new shapefile. I have also tried importing the shapefile via `rgdal::readOGR` and `raster::shapefile` but all methods have lead to the same 'collapsing' of the geometry for the country borders in the north.

R code example:

```r
LHS<-shapefile("./Longhurst.Valid/LHP.Valid.shp")

ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = LHS, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = 'dark grey')
```

How do I get R to read the shapefile the same way that QGIS appears to be reading it?

Comment: Error messages or something? Does R complain about it? Afaik, QGIS does well the job, for instance I found some issues uploading shps to my gdb (Postgis/Postgres) thanks to QGIS testing.

Comment: No complaints from R, silent on import and then comments 'Regions defined for each Polygons' when plotting in ggplot

Comment: No debugging option? A verbose mode perhaps? Try  topology check in QGIS to find unclosed/unfinished parts (you may probably dealing with a multipolygon feature), be careful with that geometry type because experience tells me that you may import it as simple polygon geometry instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `sp` classes for spatial data if you can avoid it. Use `sf`:

```
library(sf)
LHS = st_read("Longhurst_world_v4_2010.shp")
```

Don't use `geom_polygon` for spatial data. Use `geom_sf`:

```
ggplot(LHS) + geom_sf(fill="dark grey")
```

[image]

Personally I'd avoid `ggplot` altogether for maps, and start by just using plain old plot:

```
plot(st_geometry(LHS), col="dark grey")
```

[image]

For thematic maps, use `tmap`. But you may have to switch off the `s2` processing in `sf` because treating this as spherical data fails.

```
library(tmap)
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(LHS) + tm_polygons()
```

[image]

By setting `tmap_mode("view")` you get an interactive web map.